# Post Ancestor and Child Post in Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, directory, customization

[image]

<sup>Hierarchical structure of custom post type "Book" (for example).</sup>

When we are on `Post 2-95`, I want to know:

- Does the post has this post ancestor(`Post 1-31`)?
- Does it have child posts(`Post 3-19`, `Post 3-10`)?

Then, if it has:

- an ancestor post: retrieve (object) of this post.
- a child posts: retrieve (objects) of these posts.

Comment: Compensation lack of english with image = kool +1

Comment: I hope that will help ;)

Comment: fixed english :)

Comment: N/P. We all appreciate if the OP invests the same effort into asking, as others need for answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a post represented by a post object `$p`, you can find out if post 31 is the parent via:

```
if($p->post_parent == 31){
    // it is!
} else {
    // it isn't
}
```

To figure out the children, something like:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_parent' => $p->ID,
    'post_type'   => $p->post_type
));
// if there are children, they will be contained in `$posts`
```

Finally, to determine how many levels deep down the hierarchy you are, you will need to recurse up the hierarchy `$p->parent_post == 0`, and then count how many times you needed to do that.

e.g.

```
$level = 1;
while($parent->parent_post != 0){
    $level++;
    $parent = get_post($parent->parent_post);
}
```

Comment: Simple, like 2 + 2, but if You dont know it, it is so hard...

Comment: @Vital Could you clarify why `$p->post_parent == 31` is the answer? I thought you needed to get _any_ post in between `1` and `31`. (No offense to you, Tom, just trying to clarify the question, as I've rewritten it and propably missunderstood something).

Comment: I'm thinking my answer was simpler and I covered the depth in the heirarchy

Answer (score 3):

### Check if current post is in range

We check with the function, if we are...

- in the Loop?
- in the set range?

Stick **all** the functions in your functions.php file.

```
function wpse52285_is_post_in_range( $post, int $range_from, int $range_to )
{
    // If we're IN the LOOP @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_the_loop
    if ( ! in_the_loop() )
        return false;

    // Abort if not in the allowed range
    if ( ! in_array( $post->ID, range( $range_from, $range_to ) ) )
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

### Check if we got children in range

We check, if we...

- are inside the loop?
- got children of the needed post type (can be any custom post type, post, page, attachment, link, etc.)
- the children are in range?

In case nothing was found, we return `false`, so we can make our check easier.

```
function wpse52285_get_children_in_range( $post, int $range_from, int $range_to, $post_type = 'post' )
{
    if ( ! in_the_loop() )
        return false;

    // get_children() @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children
    $children = get_children( "post_parent={$post->ID}&post_type={$post_type}" );
    if ( 0 < count( $children ) )
    {
        foreach ( $children as $child )
        {
            in_array( $id, range( $range_from, $range_to ) ) AND $in_range[] = $child;
        }
        if ( 0 < count( $in_range ) )
            return $in_range;
    }

    return false;
}
```

### Check if we got ancestors

We check, if...

- we are in the loop?
- we got ancestors?
- ancestors are in range?

In case nothing meets, we again return `false`.

```
function wpse52285_get_ancestors_in_range( $post, int $range_from, int $range_to )
{
    if ( ! in_the_loop() )
        return false;

    // get_post_ancestors @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_ancestors
    $ancestors = get_post_ancestors( $post->ID );
    foreach ( $ancestors as $ancestor )
    {
        in_array( $ancestor->ID, range( $range_from, $range_to ) ) AND $in_range[] = $ancestor;
    }
    if ( 0 < count( $in_range ) )
        return $in_range;

    return false;
}
```

### Template

Now we can use it in any template like this:

```
// The loop
if have_posts() : while( have_posts() ): the_post();
    global $post;

    // Is our current post in range?
    if ( wpse52285_is_post_in_range( $post, 2, 95 ) )
    {
        // Are any child posts in range?
        $children = wpse52285_get_children_in_range( $post, 3, 19 );
        if ( $children )
        {
            // Do stuff with the children
        }

        // Are any ancestors in range?
        $ancestors = wpse52285_get_ancestors_in_range( $post, 1, 31 );
        if ( $ancestors )
        {
            // Do stuff with the ancestors 
        }
    }
endwhile;
endif;
```